# prestashop c# authentication with metro app

Tags: c#, authentication, microsoft-metro, prestashop

Hi I have been fighting this for a few days now and I am getting no-where

Prestashop a php application is a web shopping cart. It uses REST services and CRUD calls.
1. how can Crud be used with rest ? they are two different types of calls ?
2. how do I authenticate with crud\ rest ? I am a newbie at metro apps and really need some guidance thanks

I have the following code

```
    private string clientId = "1LNTNMSMY285VLT28K7L345r345345T";
    private string logonUristring = "dignity-network.org/api/";
    private string redirectUristring = "http://dignity-network.org/api/";
    private string header = "http://";


    client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", header, clientId, logonUristring));

protected async void opened()
    {
        var task = client.GetAsync("products");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await task;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //gets back 200 success code
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(content, "My MessageDialog Box");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, CRUD maps pretty directly to REST, as long as your service supports the full range of HTTP verbs.

Regarding authentication, there is no authentication defined in REST, so you just use whatever kind of authentication your service needs.

In short, you'd be better off asking Prestashop these questions.

Comment: Prestashop gives a key that needs to be issued with the url http://1LNTNMSMY285VLT28K7L345r345345T@dignity-network.org/api/